# Programmatically resizing a nib makes inactive area

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPad app with a split view controller which implements some code to show/hide the `tableview` on the left.

The right hand side (the detail controller) is a custom `UIView` (specifically) which is loaded from a nib at runtime - this works fine.

If I hide the master then the detail resizes to fill the screen, as you'd expect, but an area suspiciously similar in width to that of the master `tableview` is then inactive along the far right of the detail - buttons placed there can not be clicked and you cannot scroll there.

I assume somehow that the resizing is causing this to happen but I cannot work out why...

As requested I use the following code to hide the master:

```
SplitViewController *splitViewController = (SplitViewController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

splitViewController.shouldHideMasterController = !splitViewController.shouldHideMasterController;

[splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
[splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
[self updateTextView];
```

Comment: So what resizing rules do you have?

Comment: Can you give sample code of how do you hide your master? Have you set autolayout constraints in your nib?

Comment: I've just updated the question to show the code

Comment: @Wain - I'm not sure what you mean? I think I've got the programatic text view simple constrained to the right edge of the view because it FILLS with text when I resize, it just ignores most input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this kind of behaviour happen a lot when developing iOS app, the thing to realise is that UIViews do not crop drawing of their subviews but will not let you interact with subview that are outs side their bounds. Check that your content that you can not click on is not outside the frame of any of its superviews.

Comment: Apologies for being ignorant, but I'm not entirely sure how to check that...?

Comment: This can be a bit fiddle to work out sometimes, you can set 'Clip Subviews' in interface builder or set their background colour to something really conspicuous for potential culprit view, or you can place break points in Xcode and inspect the potential culprit views frame. I usually use the background colour method initially because you can set the background colour for a few different view with different colours, making it clear which view is the issue.

Comment: Usually it means you haven't set the resizing mask correctly (or Autolayout), but if that is not applicable to you you will have to change the frame manually in code as the View changes size.

Comment: You were right, I clipped the subviews and found the culprit - a view within a view wasn't resizing properly so I overrode the willLayoutSubviews appropriately and adjusted the frame manually therein! Thanks