# UIButton doesn't work inside UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with some buttons that works fine when I add as subview, but when I present this viewcontroller in `UIPopoverController` none of the buttons trigger actions. Someone knows that problem ?

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard" bundle:nil];
menuViewController =  (MenuListViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuviewcontroller"];
```

Buttons inside viewcontroller works if I use:

```
[self.view menuViewController.view];
```

But I want to use

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:menuViewController];
```

Comment: I just have UIViewController with buttons and actions using storyboard to link it, but when i present viewcontroller using popover buttons doesn`t trigger any action.
-(IBAction)menuItemTouched:(UIButton *)sender{ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to look at when you can't interact with UI elements, especially after frame resizes, is to check that your elements are not outside of their parents bounds, check my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858057/programatically-resizing-a-nib-makes-inactive-area/20869511#20869511)

Comment: Thanks, i adjusted my subviews and fixed it